# How do i get these output?

Tags: python, algorithm

How do i get these output?

```
def pair(str):
  count = 0
  for ch in str:
    if ch == 'HLL':
      return "Alice"
    if ch == 'EO':
        return "Bob"
    if ch == "WORL":
        return "Alice"
    if ch == "D":
        return "Bob"
    else:
        return "Hello World"
    print(count)
```

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot clearer on what you want to do, right now you are iterating characters in a string but comparing characters to larger strings. You're also returning in an if/else statement so your `for` loop will never execute more than once. The last `print(count)` is unreachable code.

Comment: Please edit the question to better explain what you want. Right now, you are showing us a function in python, and this function is obviously wrong and not doing what you want it to do. But we have no idea what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

`return` is executed before `print`, which means this method ends before `print`. `print` is not reachable in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you want to get data type of these output.
So, I guess 2 data types and write them here.

1. String

```
def pair(str):
    count = 0
    result = ''
    for ch in str:
        count += 1
        if ch == 'HLL':
            result += "Alice"
        if ch == 'EO':
            result += "Bob"
        if ch == "WORL":
            result += "Alice"
        if ch == "D":
            result += "Bob"
        else:
            result += "Hello World"
    print(count)
    return result
```

2. List

```
def pair(str):
    count = 0
    result = list()
    for ch in str:
        count += 1
        if ch == 'HLL':
            result.append("Alice")
        if ch == 'EO':
            result.append("Bob")
        if ch == "WORL":
            result.append("Alice")
        if ch == "D":
            result.append("Bob")
        else:
            result.append("Hello World")
    print(count)
    return result
```

Since return is the code that ends the function(def), for loop is executed only once in your code

- For reference, if the input is a string(str), only one letter is entered in 'ch' in the for loop, so nothing other than D will be identified.

Comment: There is some good advice in this answer, but please don't encourage calling the argument of the function `str`. `str` is already the name of the builtin class for strings in python. Shadowing builtins is bad practice and can lead to unexpected consequences.